# Open a date in a .txt into DateEdit Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, date

I'm trying to save in a .txt a date of DataEdit in QtDesigner, and later to open the .txt and put the date into the DataEdit.

save is okey:

```
QTextStream out(&sFile);

        out << ui.lineEdit_2->text()<< "\n"
            << ui.lineEdit->text()<< "\n" 
            << ui.dateEdit->text();
```

Open (here it is the problem):

```
  QTextStream in(&sFile);
        QString text = in.readLine();
        QString name = in.readLine();
        QDateEdit fecha = in.readLine();

        sFile.close();
        ui.lineEdit_2->setText(text);
        ui.lineEdit->setText(name);
        ui.dateEdit->date(fecha);
```

Error   1   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'QString' to 'QDateEdit'
Error   2   error C2660: 'QDateTimeEdit::date' : function does not take 1 arguments

I don't know like to change this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the best way to store settings. You store it as text, but don't control text encoding, date format, etc.

Anyway the minimal changes of your code are the following:

```
QDate fecha = QDate::fromString(in.readLine());
...
ui.dateEdit->setDate(fecha);
```

Comment: the date is not change. save well, but it isn't opening the date entered

Comment: with qDebug()<< fecha in the Output appear QDate("")

Comment: In which format is the date saved? `QDate::fromString(const QString & string, Qt::DateFormat format)` has a second parameter, where you can specify the date format. What is the output of `qDebug() << ui.dateEdit->text()`?

Comment: dd/mm/yy by default I think

Comment: the OutPut is `ui.dateEdit->setDate(fecha);`

Comment: If the output of `qDebug() << ui.dateEdit->text()` has format **dd/mm/yy**, then try this code: `QDate fecha = QDate::fromString(in.readLine(), "dd/MM/yy");`.

Answer (score 1):

QDateEdit is a widget not a [QDate](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qdate.html#operator-lt-lt-105) and QDate can be serialized the widget doesn't make sense to serialize - you are actually writing down the text of a QDateEdit and want to create a QDateEdit from that text.

Instead you need to serialize the QDate of that edit and then get QDate back and set it to the ui.dateEdit.

Answer (score 0):

try the `QDate::fromString()` method to get a `QDate`from it. then just call `QDateEdit::setDate(const QDate& date)`

soo long zai